# Is there a difference in the session storage behavior between Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, session-storage

I'm finding a difference between the chrome and firefox regarding session storage. I don't know if it's something I'm doing wrong or if this is the behavior of each of them.

Situation: I need the session storage to work by tab and not by window. In firefox I get this result, but not in chrome. Here's a Plunker I made to simulate the situation: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WIRa7RbbYHwaFR9dlfL7)

```
if(!($scope.fooBarKey = sessionStorage.getItem('fooBarKey'))) {
  $scope.fooBarKey = Math.floor(Math.random() * 900000) + 100000;
  sessionStorage.setItem('fooBarKey', $scope.fooBarKey);
}
```

Thanks for listening

---

Obs: Replying to a question by charlietfl

If you open my Plunker in 3 tabs on chrome the value that is saved and recovered (for each tab) is the same. If you open 3 tabs on firefox the value that is saved and recovered (for each tab) is different

Comment: Please be more specific about the differences you are encountering. We shouldn't have to go off site to understand the problem in full

Comment: @charlietfl If you open my Plunker in 3 tabs on chrome the value that is saved and recovered (for each tab) is the same. If you open 3 tabs on firefox the value that is saved and recovered (for each tab) is different.

Comment: And what are your expectations? Note that your `if` is using invalid comparison. Not at all sure what this code is expected to do

Comment: can't repro on chrome 51 on mac. Is the `<base>` related or just some dust of trials to fix the issue ?

Comment: @charlietfl and Kaiido I found my answer. Thanks for listening.

Answer (score 1):

After some study and asking some wise men for help here at work, I came to understand what I was doing wrong.

In fact each chrome session has its own sessionStorage. The problem is that I was duplicating tabs instead of opening a new one. The chrome to duplicate a tab uses the window.open and generates a daughter tab that shares all the info from it's parent, including sessionStorage.